# cohomology ring structure of connected sum

Tags: algebraic-topology

Let M, N be connected manifolds of dimension $n$ with known $H^*(M)$ and $H^*(N).$
Let $k,l>0$ and $k+l=n.$ Finally, let $(\alpha,\beta)\in H^k(M)\oplus H^k(N)=H^k(M\#N)$ and $(\alpha',\beta')\in H^l(M)\oplus H^l(N)=H^l(M\#N).$

How do we calculate $\alpha\smile \beta?$

I've been told $(\alpha,\beta) \smile (\alpha',\beta')=\alpha\smile \alpha'+\beta\smile \beta',$ but I don't get why it is so.

Thank you.

Comment: Does this help: https://mathoverflow.net/questions/98376/cup-products-of-connected-sum?

Comment: @ThomasRot
No, I've seen this post before, but it is difficult for me to understand. I don't get what the maps in the cofibration are, why it is a cofibration, how the fact that it's a cofibration helps with cohomology, and what is meant by the ideal in the definition of $R$.